# How can I remove space before paragraph for the text in the header row of a custom table style?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-365

I have a template with a custom table style. The text in each cell has some space before paragraph. This works fine for the cells but in the header row I want to eliminate the extra space.
[image]
I'm doing it manually right now by selecting the text and clicking **Removed Space Before Paragraph**, but I would like to build this into the custom table style.

Are there any settings in the table style editor that will accomplish this?

Comment: What is the source of your Custom Table Style? Is it from one of Word’s built-in Table Styles?

Comment: @RichMichaels My custom table style is based on the Table Grid Light style from the built-in list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three factors that could effect the spacing before text in a table cell.

1. Paragraph style of the text that included a Spaces Before setting.
2. Table property setting on the table or cells in the table that included a custom cell margin setting.
3. A specified height on the table row.

The table design, Table Grid Light, that you used as the starting point for your table does not have any special Table Property settings for Cell Margins or Row Height ... that leaves the Paragraph Style that you are using, which most likely is Normal.

So, answering your question directly ... No there isn’t any Table Style Editor setting that you could use to accomplish what you want.

What you can do is make a Custom Paragraph Style, for example call it TableHeader, with the Spaces Before setting of 0 Points Before and other properties that you require such as Bold or Centering and apply it to the header row of your tables.

If you are trying to create an overall style for tables that will be used in the current document and others, you might consider the AuthorTec Table Styles add-in. It’s from a third party, I am the author. Do a web search on AuthorTec Tables for more information.

Comment: The paragraph style was the problem. In my template the Normal style had 6pt spacing before. I removed that and the extra space in the row disappears. This change affects all rows in the table so, I'll setup a table header paragraph style as you recommend.

Answer (score 0):

In Word, in Text or in a Table, go to Paragraph (Home Ribbon) and then to Spacing (before and after).   Set vertical spacing here.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you'll need to edit the custom table style, perhaps a Header-2 style or something, is defined and applied to that table's column header; just guessing? If the custom table style is reused often, then I would want to change the template so that successive uses retains the changes and prevents future manual changes. On a Mac today, but memory tells me you'd need to select the table, nav to the home tab, click Manage Styles button, defaults tab...